# Convert variable integer into single digit word form in a list

Tags: python

Create a function named list_numbers_in_words(...) which receives as a parameter a positive integer number and returns a list with the words corresponding to each digit, in the same order as the digits appear in the number.
As an example, the following code fragment:

```
res = list_numbers_in_words(5438)
print(res)
```

should produce the output:

```
['five', 'four', 'three', 'eight']
```

Code atempted:

```
def list_numbers_in_words(num):
    l = list(num);
    single_digits = ["zero", "one", "two", "three",  
                     "four", "five", "six", "seven",  
                     "eight", "nine"]; 
    if (l==1):  
        print(single_digits[ord(num[0]) - '0']); 
        return; 
    x = 0; 
    while (x < len(num)):
     if (l >= 3): 
        if (ord(num[x]) - 48 != 0): 
                print(single_digits[ord(num[x]) - 48],  
                                           end = " "); 
                print(tens_power[l - 3], end = " ");
        l -= 1; 
     else: 
        if (ord(num[x]) - 48 == 1):  
                sum = (ord(num[x]) - 48 + 
                       ord(num[x]) - 48); 
                print(two_digits[sum]); 
                return; 
        elif (ord(num[x]) - 48 == 2 and 
                  ord(num[x + 1]) - 48 == 0): 
                print("twenty"); 
                return; 
        else: 
                i = ord(num[x]) - 48; 
                if(i > 0): 
                    print(tens_multiple[i], end = " "); 
                else: 
                    print("", end = ""); 
                x += 1; 
                if(ord(num[x]) - 48 != 0): 
                    print(single_digits[ord(num[x]) - 48]); 
        x += 1;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Quick comment on the code: no need to use semicolons in python.

Answer (score 5):

```
def list_numbers_in_words(n):
    ns = str(n)
    single_digits = ["zero", "one", "two", "three",  
                     "four", "five", "six", "seven",  
                     "eight", "nine"]
    return [
        single_digits[int(nsi)]
        for nsi in ns
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An almost-one-liner.

(Explanations:
First, the integer is converted to a list of strings, e.g `['5','4','3','8']`. Second, query the index of `single_digits` through `map` function to actual english format, e.g `single_digits [0] = 'zero'`.    Last, now the result is almost ready, we just need to unpack  from `map object` to a `list`, using `[*the_map_object]`)

```
 def list_numbers_in_words(x):

    single_digits = ["zero", "one", "two", "three",  
                     "four", "five", "six", "seven",  
                     "eight", "nine"]

    return [*map(lambda n: single_digits[int(n)],list(str(x)))]
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to supplement the code in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `mapping dict` to map numbers into words.

```
def list_numbers_in_words(numbers):
    number_to_word_dict = {
        "0": "zero",
        "1": "one",
        "2": "two",
        "3": "three",
        "4": "four",
        "5": "five",
        "6": "six",
        "7": "seven",
        "8": "eight",
        "9": "nine",
    }

    return [number_to_word_dict.get(number, '') for number in str(numbers)]
```

**Input:**

> 1234

**Output:**

> ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `num2words` for this if you don't want to create this list by yourself

Installation:

`pip install num2words`

Code example:

```py
from num2words import num2words

def list_numbers_in_words(n):
    return [num2words(i) for i in str(n)]
```